# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jdae'

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line

I used to have this program installed on my PC, then I factory reset my PC because I was going to sell it, but then I didn't end up selling it, so I am trying to install this program again. The programs link is https://github.com/Jess-Doit/jess-doit-archive-engine. I installed python 3.7 and then changed into the directory jdae which is where the main start file is found, once i did py -3 start_jdae.py, I got this error
C:\Users\me\Downloads\jess-doit-archive-engine-main\jdae>py -3 start_jdae.py
`Traceback (most recent call last): File "start_jdae.py", line 8, in <module> import jdae.src.logos as logos ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jdae'`

I tried looking onilne for help, but couldn't find any, and now im here. Any solutions would be appreciated

Comment: If you're already in the jdae folder, the imports should be `import src.logos as logos` and `from src.configmanager import ConfigManager`

Comment: @RJAdriaansen It doesn't work.